# jQuery Scroll function after 100px and then again after 600px

Tags: scroll

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#navigatie ul li a').css('color' , '#616161') 
    }
    else{
    $('#navigatie ul li a').css('color' , '#FFF')
    }
    });
});
```

If I do this it wil work, but if I make this it doesn't work, I just want, 
If I scroll down 100pixxel then my navigate wil get 
a other color but if go futur down 400px it wil get a other color, that's what
I want. Sorry for my bad english

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#navigatie ul li a').css('color' , '#616161') 
}
else{
$('#navigatie ul li a').css('color' , '#FFF')
}
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 600) {
$('#navigatie ul li a').css('color' , '#F00') 
}
else{
$('#navigatie ul li a').css('color' , '#FFF')
}
```

});
});

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but nobody answered, so I figured I would.

Have you tried jQuery Waypoints?

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started

You can set the `option` -> `offset` to a pixel or percentage value.

Example:

```
$('#example-offset-pixels').waypoint(function() {
  // do something here
}, { offset: 100 });
```

That should do the trick no problem.